# effect on the determinant of X'X (2 x 2) if one of the columns of X is Linear transformation of the other

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a (2 x 2) matrix X such that the first column X1 = c + aX2 where X2 is the second column, how can I show that X'X is not invertible?

(1) X = $\begin{bmatrix} c + a x_{21} & x_{21} \\ c+ ax_{22} & x_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

and thus

(2) X'X = $\begin{bmatrix} (c + a x_{21})^2 + (c+ ax_{22})^2  & (c + a x_{21})x_{21} + (c + a x_{22})x_{22} \\ (c + a x_{21})x_{21} + (c + a x_{22})x_{22} & x_{21} + ^2 x_{22}^2\end{bmatrix}$

When I then take the determinant of X'X my algebra gets messy at at the end I never find a determinant of zero. Am I approaching the question incorrectly? Is there an better way to show that X'X is not invertible in this case? Or is it that I'm wrong in thinking it X'X should be singular in this case? If I'm correct about the non-invertibility of X'X, then is there a way to prove it for X'X when X is a (T x 2) matrix?

Comment: In general $X$ can be invertible (e.g., $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$) in which case $X'X$ is also invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X^TX$ to be not invertible it should be  $X$ not invertible.
($ \det(  X^TX)= \det(X)\det(X)$).

Generally matrix $X$ constructed in the way described above is invertible.
It would be not invertible in the case $X_1=aX_2$.